# Spring fails to connect to MySQL with RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring, encryption, openshift

I have two Docker images, one containing a Bitnami MySQL instance, the other is a java Spring app. I can run the two images locally on machine through Vagrant and they connect fine. However, I tried deploying them in an Openshift environment and now the Spring app fails to start with the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
...
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.RSAException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
...
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:543) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.encryptWithRSAPublicKey(ExportControlled.java:658) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.authentication.Sha256PasswordPlugin.encryptPassword(Sha256PasswordPlugin.java:173) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
...
Caused by: javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException: Unsupported padding OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.engineSetPadding(P11RSACipher.java:137) ~[sunpkcs11.jar:1.8.0_312]
    at javax.crypto.Cipher$Transform.setModePadding(Cipher.java:380) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:536) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
```

I'm very unfamiliar with the underlying mechanics behind java's encryption, so if anyone knows what steps I should take to resolve this it would be much appreciated.

Side question: why is the behavior of the Spring Docker image different depending on where it is run? I've always assumed the image should have all its dependencies packaged with it, so it is agnostic of where it is being run. Why would running it in Openshift affect the available crypto providers?

Comment: Did you add mysql dependency on your build file

Comment: By build file do you mean Dockerfile? What would that MySQL dependency look like exactly?

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle in you application. Docker image will give you an instance of the DB, but in order to connect to the DB, you need a DB driver which can be included as a dependency in your project

Comment: Yes maven is managing dependencies. And there is a driver included with the project, if you look at the top of the stack trace it’s Driver library throwing the exception

Comment: openshift usually cripples permissions and privileges for an application running inside it, could you try running the app with the `root` user? this should give a better sense of the underlying cause of the issue